# ...should not be upheld to the performance, roadworthiness, and environmental standards

Tags: word-meaning

This is an excerpt from [a CNN article](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/11/03/world/classic-car-electric-ev-c2e-climate-spc-intl-hnk/index.html).

> Some car enthusiast groups, such as the Federation of British Historic
> Vehicle Clubs, believe vintage vehicles should not be **upheld** to the
> performance, roadworthiness, and environmental standards applied to
> modern cars.

I looked up 'uphold' in a few dictionaries but couldn't find any meaning which would be natural in passive voice in the above context.

I think 'be subject to' is more appropriate for the above context.

What is the meaning of 'be upheld to something'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mistake. The word should probably have been *held*:

> vintage vehicles should not be **held** to the ... standards...

You might say that in the case of vintage vehicles, the standards should not be upheld.